# Counting the number of n-digit words over {0,...,m-1} that have even number of 0′s

Tags: combinatorics

Counting the number of words over $\{{0,...,m-1\}}$ of length n with an even number of $0's$.

I Know that the answer Should be $\frac{m^n+(m-2)^n}{2}$ but I don't know how to explain this.
I have managed to get the following expression: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k}(m-1)^{n-2k}$$
The idea behind this sum is that we go through all the even numbers from $0$ to $n$ and each time we choose $2k$ indices to place the $0's$ in them. For each of the rest $n-2k$ digits we have $m-1$ options($\{{1,...,m-1\}}$).
Giving the sum expression to an automatic solver yields the intended answer but I don't know the process behind it.

I need help with achieving the intended answer in a direct way or by algebraic operations on the sum expression.

Comment: An alternative strategy to Ben Grossman's answer: Let $f(n)$ denote the desired quantity, and by considering cases for the last digit, obtain $f(n+1)=(m-1)f(n)+(m^n-f(n)).$ Expand this to write $f(n)$ as a sum, and notice it's essentially a geometric series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the following way of accounting for the terms that are "skipped" in the sum:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k}(m-1)^{n-2k} = 
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left[\frac{1 + (-1)^j}{2} \right]\dbinom{n}{j}(m-1)^{n-j}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much 

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

Let $a_i$ be the number of words with $i$ zeroes, so
$$a_i = \binom{n}{i}(m-1)^{n-i}$$
for $0 \le i\le n$, and define $f(x) = \sum a_i x^i$, so
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(m-1)^{n-i} x^i = (x+m-1)^n$$
by the Binomial Theorem.  If we let $g(x) = (1/2) [f(x) + f(-x)]$, then
$$g(x) = \sum_{i \text{ even}} a_i x^i$$
(The odd-nummbered terms cancel out.)  So the number of words with an even number of zeroes is
$$\sum_{i \text{ even}} a_i = g(1) = \frac{f(1)+f(-1)}{2} = \frac{(1+m-1)^n + (-1+m-1)^n}{2} = \frac{m^n + (m-2)^n}{2}$$